# Unable link up wordpress with ionic android and ios script

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello I have this script purchased but I am unable to set it up. Also there is a while screen error after splash screen.

Ionic Woocommerce - Universal iOS & Android Ecommerce / Store Full Mobile App

https://codecanyon.net/item/ionic-woocommerce-universal-ios-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app/21561737

Comment: AutoHideSplashScreen=“false” try this

Comment: show your , ionic info

Comment: AutoHideSplashScreen=“false" worked for me , please answer i will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoHideSplashScreen=“false"

worked for me